Querying a collection immediately after batch commit data in it
I am noticing a behaviour where data that I create using batch commit into a collection isn't immediately available when querying. Here what I do:
// First Batch create documents from myData array. All of which have a property called ref = 'abc'
const db = admin.firestore();
const batch = db.batch();
myData.forEach((el: DocDefinition) => {
  const doc = db.collection(`some-path`).doc(el.email);
  batch.create(doc, el);
 }
});
await batch.commit();
// Later in the same context I query collection 'some-path' like so
const query = await db.collection('some-path').where('ref', '==', 'abc').get();
query.empty; // => true 

When I do the same query from firebase console, it returns results as expected, which makes me wonder if the query returning no results is because when the batch.commit() promise resolves, it doesn't mean the data has been written. And so when the query happens right after, the data isn't there yet.
If so, what's the recommended way? Should I allow some time before querying or is there another solution?

Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Where in your code are you writing documents and calling batch.commit()?  What is batch.create()?  That's not a native Firestore API.  Please edit the question to show a complete minimal reproducible example that doesn't work the way you expect.  We should be able to copy the code and see the same result ourselves.

Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Yes, I do commit data, I have just edited my question. I am using firestore v1

If you commit a batch, it should be immediately available for querying.  If you can prove that this is not the case, you should reach out to Firebase support with a complete and specific example code that they can run to verify the behavior as you observe it.
